# How to get a top-view house in p5.js

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I'm a beginner in p5.js, this is my code till now:

```js
function setup() {
  createCanvas(600, 600);
}

function draw() {
  background(50, 168, 82);
  road();
  house();
}

function road() {
  fill(54, 59, 55);
  noStroke();
  rect(200, 0, 220, 600);


  fill(197, 222, 202);
  rect(300, 50, 40, 70);

  fill(197, 222, 202);
  rect(300, 200, 40, 70);

  fill(197, 222, 202);
  rect(300, 350, 40, 70);

  fill(197, 222, 202);
  rect(300, 500, 40, 70);
}

function house() {
  fill(209, 207, 61);
  rect(50, 50, 100, 100);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/p5@1.3.1/lib/p5.js"></script>
```

And this is the result:
[code result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7CiMj.png)

Instead of that yellow rectangle, I wanted a top-view house that looks like a house ;)
I tried, but I couldn't get a house. I'd be happy if someone could do that for me.

If you don't understand what top-view house means, you can see this image:
[image: top-view house]

The house can be the shape of any of these houses.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. "top-view house" doesn't mean much and isn't specific enough..., can you please elaborate on what exactly your desired result should look like?

Comment: Alright, I'll quickly show you an image so that you could understand it better.

Comment: I edited the question and added an image there. Because I can't add images in the comments.

Comment: It's best not to finish someone's whole program for them, but what I would recommend is learning about the quad function, and triangle function, then learn about the fill function for grayscale values. If you think of the houses as a lot of shapes, you'll notice it's all quads and triangles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want just a simple house, you can make two halves of the square different colors (to show the light hitting the two sides of the roof differently):

```js
function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
  background(0);
  noStroke();
  fill(125);
  rect(100, 100, 200, 100);
  fill(200);
  rect(100, 200, 200, 100);
}
```

If you want it to be less simple, you'll need to at least use [`triangle()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/triangle), probably also [`quad()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/quad). For both of these commands, you specify the x and y coordinates of each point in the shape. Here's an example of a slightly more complicated house:

```js
function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
  background(0);
  noStroke();
  fill(100);
  quad(50, 100, 
       350, 100, 
       300, 200, 
       100, 200
      );
  fill(200);
  quad(100, 200, 
       300, 200, 
       350, 300, 
       50, 300
      );
  fill(125);
  triangle(50, 100, 
           125, 200, 
           50, 300
          );
  triangle(350, 100, 
           275, 200, 
           350, 300
          );
}
```